Different hash output from crypto.pbkdf2Sync between Node.js 16.x and 20.x
I'm using the crypto.pbkdf2Sync function to generate a hash, but I'm getting different results between Node.js version 16.x and 20.x.
Here's my code:
const crypto = require('crypto');
const user = { password: 'apple', salt: 'test' };
const hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(user.password,user.salt,10000,512,'sha512').toString('hex');
console.log(hash);
Configuration:
keySize = 512  
iterations = 10,000  
digest = "SHA512"  
password = "1m5de731"  
salt = "45a5545979dc0f0ecc7be0d0dd32e0a7"

Results:
Node.js 16.x: hash 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
Node.js 20.x: hash 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
Questions:
Why is the hash different on Node.js 20.x?
What is the reason behind this change?
Is there any way we can generate the same hash for Node.js 20.x as we did in 16.x?
I need to maintain consistency in hash generation across different Node.js versions for my application. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Node 20.9 returns the same hash that you get on Node 16.x, namely 0xa6d4..., see online here: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/1e8j. Either you are (unintentionally) using different data/code in your Node 20.x environment or it may be a specific problem with your environment.
